# Vue JS v-for Loop to display images, string interpolation leads to error

Tags: html, vue.js, v-for

This is my data:

```
  data: () => ({
    html: [
      "../assets/html.png",
      "../assets/css.png",
      "../assets/scss.png",
      "../assets/materialize.png"
    ]
  })
```

I loop through like this, which shows the text stored in my data object:

```
<p v-for="img in html" :key="img">{{img}}</p>
```

However I can not use interpolation inside elements, so the following code does not work.

```
  <v-flex xs6 md3 v-for="img in html" :key="img">
    <img src={{img}} alt />
  </v-flex>
```

How can I do this?

Edit: No errors, but not working yet: The HTML link looks like this (working):

```
</v-flex>
  <v-flex xs6 md3><img src=../assets/html.png alt /></v-flex>
</v-layout>

src="/img/html.6ec9ec76.png"
```

Rendered by vue: `src="../assets/materialize.png`

Vue does not handle it correctly it seems!

Comment: To "interpolate" between the tags, you use `{{ }}` syntax, but to interpolate inside the opening tag, you've to use the `v-bind` directive, or the syntactic sugar with a colon only `:`.  `v-bind:src="img"`, or `:src="img"` instead of `src={{img}}`

Comment: This is a dublication, you can easly find answer in 1 min on stackoverflow

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `<img :src="img" alt />` instead

Comment: does not solve everything, no error, but nothing displayed. Updated my question

Answer (score 1):

string interpolation can only be used to display for value in attribute you have to bind it:

```
<v-flex xs6 md3 v-for="img in html" :key="img">
    <img :src="img" alt />
</v-flex>
```

Comment: do i have to change the links in the data object? No error, but nothing gets displayed